# T/SQL - Time related calculations

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#TempTable') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #TempTable
CREATE TABLE #TempTable
    (
      [ID] INT NOT NULL ,
      [Value] VARCHAR(50) NULL ,
      [Date] DATE NULL ,
      [Time] TIME(7) NULL ,
      [Duration] INT NULL ,
      [srcFile] VARCHAR(50) NULL,   
    )
INSERT  #TempTable
        ( [ID], [Value], [Date], [Time], [Duration], [srcFile] )
VALUES  ( 1, N'One', CAST(N'2014-07-29' AS DATE), CAST(N'23:34:00' AS TIME), 1710, N'sF1' ),
        ( 2, N'One', CAST(N'2014-07-30' AS DATE), CAST(N'00:00:10' AS TIME), 1710, N'sF1' ),
        ( 3, N'One', CAST(N'2014-07-30' AS DATE), CAST(N'01:30:00' AS TIME), 1710, N'sF1' ),
        ( 4, N'One', CAST(N'2014-07-30' AS DATE), CAST(N'01:54:00' AS TIME), 1710, N'sF1' ),
        ( 5, N'One', CAST(N'2014-07-30' AS DATE), CAST(N'13:30:00' AS TIME), 1710, N'sF1' ),
        ( 6, N'One', CAST(N'2014-07-30' AS DATE), CAST(N'13:57:00' AS TIME), 1710, N'sF2' ),
        ( 7, N'One', CAST(N'2014-07-30' AS DATE), CAST(N'23:34:00' AS TIME), 1710, N'sF1' ),
        ( 8, N'One', CAST(N'2014-07-31' AS DATE), CAST(N'00:00:10' AS TIME), 1710, N'sF2' ),
        ( 9, N'One', CAST(N'2014-07-31' AS DATE), CAST(N'00:10:10' AS TIME), 1710, N'sF3' ),
        ( 10, N'One', CAST(N'2014-08-01' AS DATE), CAST(N'00:00:00' AS TIME), 1710, N'sF2' ),
        ( 11, N'One', CAST(N'2014-08-01' AS DATE), CAST(N'00:00:00' AS TIME), 1710, N'sF1' ),
        ( 12, N'One', CAST(N'2014-08-01' AS DATE), CAST(N'01:00:00' AS TIME), 1710, N'sF3' ),
        ( 13, N'One', CAST(N'2014-08-01' AS DATE), CAST(N'01:00:00' AS TIME), 1710, N'sF4' ),
        ( 14, N'Two', CAST(N'2014-08-01' AS DATE), CAST(N'00:01:00' AS TIME), 1710, N'sF2' )

SELECT  *
FROM    #TempTable
```

Base Table

```
ID  Value   Date    Time        Duration    srcFile
1   One 7/29/2014   23:34:00    1710        sF1
2   One 7/30/2014   0:00:10     1710        sF1
3   One 7/30/2014   1:30:00     1710        sF1
4   One 7/30/2014   1:54:00     1710        sF1
5   One 7/30/2014   13:30:00    1710        sF1
6   One 7/30/2014   13:57:00    1710        sF2
7   One 7/30/2014   23:34:00    1710        sF1
8   One 7/31/2014   0:00:10     1710        sF2
9   One 8/1/2014    0:00:00     1710        sF2
10  Two 8/1/2014    0:01:00     1710        sF2
11  One 8/1/2014    0:00:00     1710        sF1
```

Requirement:

When [Value] + [Date] + [Time] match then Dup
    Output: Mark isDup flag with 1 and dupFIle with the srcFile for two or more records where dup condition matches.

When [Value] match and [Date] + [Time] of any two or more records fall within [Date] + [Time] PLUS (+) [Duration] then Overlap (note: when ALL matching records are DUP...they can't also be overlap..but overlap can have at least one unique record and multiple dups that fall within the duration time frame).
    Output: Mark isOverlap flag with 1 and overlapFile with the srcFile for two or more records where overlap condition matches.

This is what I tried

```
;WITH dupCTE AS (
SELECT ID, Value, [Date], [Time], Duration, srcFile
        ,CASE
            WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY  Value, [Date], [Time]) > 1 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS isDup
        ,CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY  Value, [Date], [Time]) > 1 THEN STUFF((SELECT ' - ' + srcFile 
                                FROM #TempTable T 
                                WHERE T.Value = TT.Value
                                    AND T.[Date] = TT.[Date]
                                    AND T.[Time] = TT.[Time]
                                FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 3, '')
            ELSE NULL 
            END AS dupFIle
FROM #TempTable TT
)
, overlapCTE AS (
SELECT A. ID, A.Value, A.[Date], A.[Time], A.Duration, A.srcFile, A.isDup, A.dupFIle
        ,CASE WHEN B.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 
                      ELSE 0 
        END AS 'isOverlap'
        ,CASE WHEN b.ID IS NOT NULL THEN STUFF((SELECT ' - ' + srcFile 
                    FROM #TempTable T
                    WHERE T.Value = A.Value 
                        AND  ((CAST(CAST(B.[Date] AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' ' + CAST(B.[Time] AS VARCHAR(16)) AS DateTime2) > CAST(CAST(A.[Date] AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' ' + CAST(A.[Time] AS VARCHAR(16)) AS DateTime2)  AND CAST(CAST(B.[Date] AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' ' + CAST(B.[Time] AS VARCHAR(16)) AS DateTime2) < DATEADD(SECOND, A.Duration, CAST(CAST(A.[Date] AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' ' + CAST(A.[Time] AS VARCHAR(16)) AS DateTime2)))
                        OR    (CAST(CAST(A.[Date] AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' ' + CAST(A.[Time] AS VARCHAR(16)) AS DateTime2) > CAST(CAST(B.[Date] AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' ' + CAST(B.[Time] AS VARCHAR(16)) AS DateTime2)  AND CAST(CAST(A.[Date] AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' ' + CAST(A.[Time] AS VARCHAR(16)) AS DateTime2) < DATEADD(SECOND, B.Duration, CAST(CAST(B.[Date] AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' ' + CAST(B.[Time] AS VARCHAR(16)) AS DateTime2))))
                    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 3, '')
        ELSE NULL 
        END AS 'overlapFiles'
FROM dupCTE A LEFT JOIN dupCTE B
  ON   A.Value = B.Value
      AND  ((CAST(CAST(B.[Date] AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' ' + CAST(B.[Time] AS VARCHAR(16)) AS DateTime2) > CAST(CAST(A.[Date] AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' ' + CAST(A.[Time] AS VARCHAR(16)) AS DateTime2)  AND CAST(CAST(B.[Date] AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' ' + CAST(B.[Time] AS VARCHAR(16)) AS DateTime2) < DATEADD(SECOND, A.Duration, CAST(CAST(A.[Date] AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' ' + CAST(A.[Time] AS VARCHAR(16)) AS DateTime2))) 
      OR    (CAST(CAST(A.[Date] AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' ' + CAST(A.[Time] AS VARCHAR(16)) AS DateTime2) > CAST(CAST(B.[Date] AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' ' + CAST(B.[Time] AS VARCHAR(16)) AS DateTime2)  AND CAST(CAST(A.[Date] AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' ' + CAST(A.[Time] AS VARCHAR(16)) AS DateTime2) < DATEADD(SECOND, B.Duration, CAST(CAST(B.[Date] AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' ' + CAST(B.[Time] AS VARCHAR(16)) AS DateTime2))))
WHERE A.isDup = 1 OR 
B.ID IS NOT NULL 
)

SELECT * FROM overlapCTE
DROP TABLE #TempTable
```

Current Output

```
ID  Value   Date            Time        Duration    srcFile     isDup   dupFIle     isOverlap   overlapFiles
1   One     2014-07-29      23:34:00    1710        sF1         0       NULL        1           sF1 - sF1 - sF1 - sF1 - sF1 - sF2 - sF1 - sF2 - sF2 - sF1
2   One     2014-07-30      00:00:10    1710        sF1         0       NULL        1           sF1 - sF1 - sF1 - sF1 - sF1 - sF2 - sF1 - sF2 - sF2 - sF1
3   One     2014-07-30      01:30:00    1710        sF1         0       NULL        1           sF1 - sF1 - sF1 - sF1 - sF1 - sF2 - sF1 - sF2 - sF2 - sF1
4   One     2014-07-30      01:54:00    1710        sF1         0       NULL        1           sF1 - sF1 - sF1 - sF1 - sF1 - sF2 - sF1 - sF2 - sF2 - sF1
5   One     2014-07-30      13:30:00    1710        sF1         0       NULL        1           sF1 - sF1 - sF1 - sF1 - sF1 - sF2 - sF1 - sF2 - sF2 - sF1
6   One     2014-07-30      13:57:00    1710        sF2         0       NULL        1           sF1 - sF1 - sF1 - sF1 - sF1 - sF2 - sF1 - sF2 - sF2 - sF1
7   One     2014-07-30      23:34:00    1710        sF1         0       NULL        1           sF1 - sF1 - sF1 - sF1 - sF1 - sF2 - sF1 - sF2 - sF2 - sF1
8   One     2014-07-31      00:00:10    1710        sF2         0       NULL        1           sF1 - sF1 - sF1 - sF1 - sF1 - sF2 - sF1 - sF2 - sF2 - sF1
9   One     2014-08-01      00:00:00    1710        sF2         1       sF2 - sF1   0           NULL
11  One     2014-08-01      00:00:00    1710        sF1         1       sF2 - sF1   0           NULL
```

Desired Output

```
ID  Value   Date            Time        Duration    srcFile     isDup       dupFIle     isOverLap       overlapFile
1   One     2014-07-29      24:34:00    1710        sF1         0           NULL        1               sF1 - sF1
2   One     2014-07-30      00:00:10    1710        sF1         0           NULL        1               sF1 - sF1
3   One     2014-07-30      01:30:00    1710        sF1         0           NULL        1               sF1 - sF1
4   One     2014-07-30      01:54:00    1710        sF1         0           NULL        1               sF1 - sF1
5   One     2014-07-30      13:30:00    1710        sF1         0           NULL        1               sF1 - sF2
6   One     2014-07-30      13:57:00    1710        sF2         0           NULL        1               sF2 - sF1
7   One     2014-07-30      24:34:00    1710        sF1         0           NULL        1               sF1 - sF2
8   One     2014-07-31      00:00:10    1710        sF2         0           NULL        1               sF2 - sF1
9   One     2014-08-01      00:00:00    1710        sF2         1           sF2 - sF1   0               NULL
10  Two     2014-08-01      00:01:00    1710        sF2         0           NULL        0               NULL
11  One     2014-08-01      00:00:00    1710        sF1         1           sF1 - sF2   0               NULL
```

I am not meeting the requirement. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Update:
Added Current Output

Update2:
Found a mistake in Dup CTE (ID was used instead of Value).
The desired output is still left to be desired.

Update3:
Progress folks, we are very close. Now overlap logic is "working." The one major issue is the overlapFIles. It should only list the files for the records that do overlap each others (right now, it's listing all the files from overlapCTE output instead of specifically listing only those that meet the WHERE within the STUFF query). Also, is there a way to get that unique record listed?

Update4: Added more records to see if duplicates and overlap queries can accommodate more than just two records.

Comment: How is your current output different from the desired output?   What specific goal are you not meeting?

Comment: Sorry, should have added that in the first place. Done!

Comment: I still can't figure out the solution to get desired output...:(

Comment: Please update your output table to reflect input IDs 12 through 14.

Comment: In `overlapFiles` can you show what IDs each represents.  The file names aren't diverse enough to give clarity.

Comment: I will update the output of the SELECT query. thx for reminding. Unfortunately, I can't use IDs in the dup/overlapFiles field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you exactly what you're after:

```
With CTE as (Select T.ID ID1, T.srcFile + ' - ' + c.srcFile over1, '1' as isDup from
#TempTable T
INNER JOIN #TempTable c on T.Value = c.Value and c.ID <> T.ID and (Cast(C.Date as datetime) + Cast(C.Time as datetime)) = (Cast(T.Date as datetime) + Cast(T.Time as datetime))),

CTE2 as
(Select T.ID ID1, c.ID ID2, T.srcFile + ' - ' + c.srcFile over1, c.srcFile + ' - ' + T.srcFile over2, '1' as isOverLap from
#TempTable T
INNER JOIN #TempTable c on T.Value = c.Value and c.ID <> T.ID
Where DateAdd(second, c.Duration, Cast(C.Date as datetime) + Cast(C.Time as datetime)) > (Cast(T.Date as datetime) + Cast(T.Time as datetime)) and (Cast(C.Date as datetime) + Cast(C.Time as datetime)) < (Cast (T.Date as datetime) + Cast(T.Time as datetime)))

Select T.*, ISNULL((Select top 1 c.isDup from CTE c where c.ID1 = T.ID) ,0) isDup
 ,(Select substring((select ',' + c1.over1 as [text()] from CTE c1 where c1.ID1 = T.ID for xml path ('')),2,1000)) dupFile
 ,ISNULL((select Top 1 case isOverLap when 1 then 1 else 0 end from CTE2 c where c.ID1 = T.ID or C.ID2 = T.ID),0) isOverLap
 ,(Select substring((select case when T.ID = C.ID1 then ',' + c.over1 else ',' + c.over2 end as [text()] from CTE2 c where c.ID1 = T.ID or C.ID2 = T.ID for xml path('')),2,1000)) OverlapFile

from #TempTable T
```

Comment: oh mann...got the following error. "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression." :(

I placed this after the insert statements and ran the the whole selection..

Comment: @user1569220 Did you run this exact code or did you add code to it?

Comment: @user1569220  It seems to work for me ok. After your insert statements remember to remove the Select * from #Temptable and replace it with GO then paste in my code and drop table #temptable at the end of it and it works for me. If you're still having issues then try adding TOP 1 before "select case isOverLap..." and "select case when T.ID = C.ID1..."

Comment: Ahh...that worked. Added more records in the temp table to see if the query works when one file is overlapping with more than 1 file. i.e. file1 - file2 overlaps and file2 - file3 overlaps. The query fails with above mentioned reason. Can you please try it from your side? thx

Comment: @user1569220 Challenge accepted! I've updated the code now and the above works for me so hopefully should for you too. It now also uses an xml path which will basically mean if there are multiple overlaps these will be added on. If you want it looking a bit neater you can add a space after the comma and then change the "2,1000" to "3,1000"

Comment: @user1569220 I've just updated the code again now so that it will cope with multiple duplicates too

Comment: Ahh, this is perfect as it give separate values for dup/overlapFile for each instance of dup/overlap. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

code follows your requirement (hopefully).
i tested it with adding more overlaps and duplicities, it work not only with 2 duplicates, overlaping files (e.g. srcFile='sF3'), but with these observations:

1. DupFile - list always ordered by filename
2. overlapfile - if there is only one file, there is no pair "sF1 - sF1", but "sF1" only - i'm not sure if this is necessary for production pursposes, but could be tweaked (not in this case yet)

---

```
with rows
(
  select [ID],[Value], [Date], [Time], [Duration], [srcFile],

    cast(cast([date] as varchar(10))+' ' +cast(time as varchar(8)) as datetime) as datetime,
    dateadd(ss,-duration,cast(cast([date] as varchar(10))+' ' +cast(time as varchar(8)) as datetime)) as date_from,
    dateadd(ss,duration,cast(cast([date] as varchar(10))+' ' +cast(time as varchar(8)) as datetime)) as date_to

  from #TempTable
  )

, dups
as
(
SELECT [value], [Date], [Time]
FROM rows
  group by [value], [Date], [Time]
  having count([ID])>1
  )

, dups_files
as
(

  select r.*
  ,
  STUFF((select ' - '+d.srcFile
        FROM rows as d 
     WHERE (r.[value]=d.value and r.time=d.time
                              and r.date=d.date)
      order by d.srcFile
       FOR xml path('')),1,3,'') as dupFile     

  FROM dups r
  )

, duplicities
as
(
  select a.id, d.dupFile
  from rows a join dups_files d
    on ( a.value=d.value and a.date=d.date
         and a.time=d.time)

  )

, overlaps_pairs
as
(

  select  f.id as id_a, d.id as id_b, f.srcfile as srcfile_a, d.srcfile as srcfile_b


  from rows f JOIN rows d
    ON (f.id<>d.id
          AND f.value=d.value
          and f.datetime between d.date_from and d.date_to)
   where not exists
          (select 1 FROM duplicities du
             where f.id=du.id)

  )

, overlaps
as
(
  select DISTINCT op.id_a as id, 1 as isoverlap

    , STUFF((select distinct ' - ' +aa.srcFile_b
       from overlaps_pairs aa
       where aa.id_a = op.id_a
       or op.id_b=aa.id_a

       for xml path ('')),1,3,'') as overlapfiles

  from overlaps_pairs op
)

select a.id, a.value, a.date, a.time, a.duration,  a.srcFile, 
case when d.id is not null then 1 else 0 end as isDup, d.dupFile,
   o.isoverlap, o.overlapfiles
  from rows a LEFT OUTER JOIN overlaps o
  on (a.id=o.id)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN duplicities d
  on (a.id=d.id);
```

Comment: Thanks ivankristof for your help. The only thing that's missing in this is when if a record that has duplicate and is also part of the overlap, the overlap is not marked as 1 with overlapFile names. Otherwise, this is a great solution. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I feel like I got sucked into using CTEs where possibly not needed. I don't know your use-case, but this table structure is pretty odd IMO; is this homework? At any rate, this should do the trick:

```
WITH 
tFullCTE AS (
    SELECT ID as ID, Value as Value, [Date] as Date, [Time] as Time, CAST(CAST([Date] AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' ' + CAST([Time] AS VARCHAR(16)) AS DateTime2) as DateTime, Duration as Duration, srcFile as srcFile
    FROM #TempTable TT
)
,dupCTE AS (
    SELECT  main.ID as FirstID, dups.ID as SecondID
    FROM    tFullCTE main
    INNER join tFullCTE dups on main.value = dups.value and main.DateTime = dups.DateTime and main.id <> dups.id
)
, 
overlapCTE AS (
    SELECT main.ID as FirstID, ovlp.ID as SecondID
    FROM tFullCTE main 
    INNER JOIN tFullCTE ovlp
        ON   main.Value = ovlp.Value
                AND  ((ovlp.DateTime > main.DateTime  AND ovlp.DateTime < DATEADD(SECOND, main.Duration, main.DateTime)) 
                        OR (main.DateTime > ovlp.DateTime  AND main.DateTime < DATEADD(SECOND, ovlp.Duration, ovlp.DateTime)))
                AND main.ID <> ovlp.ID
)

SELECT  main.*,
        CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT dup.SecondID FROM dupCTE dup WHERE dup.FirstID = main.ID) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as isDup,
        STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT ' - ' + dupDetails.srcFile 
                FROM        dupCTE dup
                INNER JOIN  tFullCTE dupDetails on dup.SecondID = dupDetails.ID
                WHERE       dup.FirstID = main.ID
            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 3, '') as dupFile,
        CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT ovlp.SecondID FROM overlapCTE ovlp WHERE ovlp.FirstID = main.ID) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as isOverlap,
        STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT ' - ' + ovlpDetails.srcFile 
                FROM        overlapCTE ovlp
                INNER JOIN  tFullCTE ovlpDetails on ovlp.SecondID = ovlpDetails.ID
                WHERE       ovlp.FirstID = main.ID
            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 3, '') as overlapFile
FROM    tFullCTE main
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I still see single file name in dupfile and overlap file (except for one record). Also added more records to test more than two dup/overlap files scenario. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH ModifiedData AS(
    SELECT
        *,
        [DateTime] = DATEADD(S, DATEDIFF(S, 0, [Time]), CAST([Date] AS DATETIME)),
        DateTimeWithDuration = DATEADD(S, Duration, DATEADD(S, DATEDIFF(S, 0, [Time]), CAST([Date] AS DATETIME)))
    FROM #TempTable
)
, Flags AS(
    SELECT 
        m.*,
        isDup = CASE 
                    WHEN COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY m.Value, m.[DateTime]) > 1 THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                END,
        dupFile =   CASE 
                        WHEN COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY m.Value, m.[DateTime]) > 1 THEN
                            STUFF((
                                SELECT ' - ' + srcFile
                                FROM ModifiedData
                                WHERE
                                    Value = m.Value
                                    AND m.DateTime = [DateTime]
                                FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 3, '')
                        ELSE NULL
                    END,
        isOverlap = CASE
                        WHEN COUNT(m2.Value) > 0 THEN 1
                        ELSE 0
                    END
    FROM ModifiedData m
    LEFT JOIN ModifiedData m2
        ON m2.value = m.Value
        AND
        (
            (m2.DateTime > m.DateTime AND m2.DateTime < m.DateTimeWithDuration)
            OR (m.DateTime > m2.DateTime AND m.DateTime < m2.DateTimeWithDuration)
        )
        AND m2.ID <> m.ID
    GROUP BY 
        m.ID, m2.ID, m.Value, m.Date, m.Time, m.Duration, m.srcFile, m.DateTime, m.DateTimeWithDuration
)
SELECT
    f.ID,
    f.Value,
    f.[Date],
    f.[Time],
    f.Duration,
    f.SrcFile,
    dupFile =   CASE 
                    WHEN isOverlap = 1 THEN
                        (SELECT f.srcFile + ' - ' + srcFile
                        FROM ModifiedData
                        WHERE                           
                            Value = f.Value
                            AND
                            (
                                ([DateTime] > f.DateTime AND [DateTime] < f.DateTimeWithDuration)
                                OR (f.DateTime > [DateTime] AND f.DateTime < DateTimeWithDuration)
                            )
                            AND ID <> f.ID
                        FOR XML PATH(''))
                    ELSE NULL
                END
FROM Flags f
ORDER BY f.ID
```

Comment: This query seems to (almost) work. Updated original INSERT statements (added more records). Can you please add isDup, dupFIle, isOverlap fields in the final query and see. When I add it (assuming dupFile in final select is actually overlapFIle), I get a weird value for dupFile for ID 8 dupFIle = 'sF2" (instead of two different files).

Comment: Seems like if I select * from flag, ID 8 record repeats twice and therefore, it's marked as dup...note sure why this is happening. Will look into this (if you know why, please let me know). Cheers!

Comment: Update: seems like in the GROUP BY, after removing m2.ID, it seems to solve the fake dup. The final query also seems to give me desired result. Just going vet this a bit more...but seems like this is it. btw, do you know how to get a dash in between multiple dup/overlap filenames?

i.e. 
with the latest update in original post, I have added a scenario where 1 file can be overlapping with 2 different files. In that case, they all should be listed. The query output "sF2 - sF1sF2 - sF3", I want it to output "sF2 - sF1 - sF2 - sF3"

Comment: Ahh, got the extra "-" working by adding stuff. Going to test this with a few more scenarios but this seems like what I am after. Cheers!